# Extract numbers and the neighboring words from text data in python

Tags: python, regex, data-extraction

I have text string data in a column of data frame

```
Text Column
The doctor has advised the patient to pay $200 for the treatment
Patient submitted the $200 operation fee but not the admit fee  $100
```

From above, how to extract numbers and the word before and after that number and store them in separate variables

```
Expected Results
Var1                 Var2     
pay $200 for
the $200 operation   fee $100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z]+) *?\$?([0-9]+) ?([a-zA-Z]*)
```

[Try it out online](https://regex101.com/r/Yp72fu/1)